# Using PIg's MultiStorage for nested structures

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Assuming I have the following set of records (stored as parquet) :

```
01, John, 250
01, John, 260
01, Daniel, 300
01, Daniel, 400
02, John, 250
02, John, 260
02, Daniel, 300
02, Daniel, 400
```

How could use Pig to create this nested folder structure

```
-- 01
-- * Daniel
-- * John 
-- 02
-- * Daniel 
-- * John
```

I know I can use

```
MultiStorage('output/pig_results', '0', 'none', ',');
```

for splitting the data dynamically by the first column, but how can I split the data dynamically by two columns ? 
Also, when I'm using the MultiStorage, output is in csv, and I'd like to save my parquet storage

Comment: If you want to split the data by two columns then merge column1 and column 2 then apply theMultiStorage function.

Comment: I have two issues with this suggestion 
1. the end result will be a flat folder structure (01 - Daniel, 01 - John etc.)
2. I cant use that method to output the data as Parquet

Comment: you can write a simple python UDF to do the same

Comment: The python UDF won't be a sufficient solution to billions of records and hundred of columns, which is my actual usecase

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Hive table partitioned by the two first columns and insert your data using your pig script, you will get directories this way:

```
-- a=01/
----- b=Daniel/
----- b=John/
-- a=02/
----- b=Daniel/ 
----- b=John/
```

Note that all the above are directories and files may be reside into `b=Daniel` or `b=John`.

Comment: You mean by using Hcatalog ? unfortunately this is not an option since we're working with a Managed Google (Dataproc) Hadoop Cluster

Comment: @Dan Hcatalog is an abstraction of Hive to simplify dealing with Hive from Pig.

Comment: This is the error I'm receive when I'm trying to activate HCatalog

pig -useHCatalog
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-api-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/*hcatalog-core-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/lib/*hbase-storage-handler-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/*hcatalog-pig-adapter-*.jar: No such file or directo